# Converting jQuery function to be reused easily without repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that fades each line of an unordered-list in and out. Right now it works for #skills_hints but I want to use it for other #named_hints. Is there a way I can reuse this code over multiple unordered lists without copying and pasting the **entire** code and just changing the IDs?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#skills_hints .hint');
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#skills_hints .hint').filter(':visible').fadeOut(800,function(){
            if($(this).next('li.hint').size()){
                $(this).next().fadeIn(800);
            }
            else{
                $('#skills_hints .hint').eq(0).fadeIn(800);
            }
        });
    },7000);    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do exactly what you have posted and the doit function (you should rename this obviously) can be called again and again passing a different id.

```
function doit(id){
    $('#'+id+' .hint');
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#'+id+' .hint').filter(':visible').fadeOut(800,function(){
            if($(this).next('li.hint').size()){
                $(this).next().fadeIn(800);
            }
            else{
                $('#'+id+' .hint').eq(0).fadeIn(800);
            }
        });
    },7000);    
}

$(function(){
   doit('skills_hints');
})
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A nice trick is turning this into a closure, in case you need a separate function to use as a callback, etc

```
function doit(id_name){
    var id = '#'+id_name + '.hint';
    return (function(){
        $(id);
        setInterval(function(){
            $(id).filter(':visible').fadeOut(800,function(){
                if($(this).next('li.hint').size()){
                    $(this).next().fadeIn(800);
                }
                else{
                    $(id).eq(0).fadeIn(800);
                }
             }
         },7000);
    })
}

//examples
doit_skills = doit('skills_hint');
doit();
doit_foo = doit('foo');
doit_foo()

names = ['a', 'b'];
for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++){
    doit(names[i])();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your code into a jQuery Plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugin)